# Output of the following

Tags: c

Code snippet

```
int main(){
    printf(5 + "GeeksQuiz"); 
    return 0;    
}
```

Output is Quiz

Can you tell me how this output is coming.
Whats the logic behind it.

Comment: `printf` prints a pointer of type `*char`. Adding 5 will print pointer+5. If you will use 6 it prints uiz. If you use an integer larger then `strlen()` your app will write nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

1. Addition is commutative. `a + b` is equal to `b + a`.
2. Adding an integer to a pointer increments follows pointer arithmetic. Adding an integer to a pointer increments it by so many elements as the integer count. So `(int*)a + b` is equal to `(int*)((uintptr_t)a + b * sizeof(int))`
3. `sizeof(char)` is always equal to 1.
4. `"GeeksQuiz"` is a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal). `strlen("GeeksQuiz")` is equal 9. Accounting for the string terminating null byte, the type of the literal is `char[10]`. It's an array of 10 characters with the content `{'G','e','e','k','s','Q','u','i','z','\0'}`.
5. The C rules say, that an array of type is converted into a pointer to the first element of that array in most contexts. That happens here: `(char[])"GeeksQuiz"` is converted into a `char*` pointer to the first character `'G'` in the string.
6. `5 + "GeeksQuiz"`: `"GeeksQuiz"` is converted to the pointer to the first character. Then that pointer is incremented by 5. So the result of `5 + "GeeksQuiz"` will be `char*` pointer that will point to the character `'Q'` inside the string literal.
7. `printf` prints the null terminated string passed to it as the first character, except for conversions that start with `%`, which does not apply here.
8. To the `printf` function is passed the address of a pointer that points to the letter `'Q'` inside the `"GeeksQuiz"` string literal.
9. `printf` increments the pointer until it will find the string terminating null byte. So it will print `{'Q','u','i','z'}`, as after `z` character it will find the null byte.